# How to show and edit microseconds in the c# DateTimePicker winform control

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker, datetime-format, infragistics

My case is that, the application is accepting raw data file with datetime precision up to microsecond, and WinForms is using `DateTimePicker` and allow the user to amend the datetime.

However, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DateTimePicker_CustomFormat), the `CustomFormat` property allows precision only up to second only.

The behavior is like that:
When I set

> this.dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;

I can get the value back directly with the microsecond part preserved.

But when the user re-selects a date by the `DateTimePicker` (even he selects the same date), the microsecond part (including the millisecond) will be gone (becomes `000000`).

Another interesting behavior is that even the control is not specified to present `HH:mm:ss`, changing to another date will still preserve the `HH:mm:ss` part.

[image]

I also tried 3rd party control `Infragistics UltraDateTimeEditor`, but according to [this](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawineditors%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawineditors.ultradatetimeeditor%7Emaskinput), it also only supports precision up to second only.

Hence, my question is that is there any way to make the control with precision up to micro-second instead of second only? Or I must make my own user control to deal with this requirement?

Comment: When you choose a `DateTime` using the `DateTimePicker`, how would you pick the microseconds? There is no UI for that. The `DateTime` picker only gives you the option to pick a time down to the second. Do you want to preserve the microseconds from the previous `DateTime`? If so, why? What if someone wanted to change the microseconds? The `DateTimePicker` doesn't give you that option.

Comment: Also, according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat?view=net-5.0 there is no format for microseconds which is "F" according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your comments. For your 1st comment, yes, I want to preserve the microsecond at least when the user re-select the same date. Sometimes, the user will say that I choose the same date, why the microsecond part is gone. Sure, it is better to make the DateTimePicker (or any other ways) to have a control to support microseconds. For your 2nd comment, the page you showed is just a general format string of DateTime, but for the CustomFormat property in DateTimePicker control, you cannot use "ffffff"

Comment: @kzfid: The `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraDateTimeEditor` control does not support milliseconds: [UltraDateTimeEditor support for milliseconds](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/42196/ultradatetimeeditor-support-for-milliseconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i'd make my life easier here and just place a numericupdown visually adjacent to the date time picker, store the microseconds of the source date time in it and add them onto the datetimepicker.Value when the user picks..

```
dtp.ValueChanged += (sender,args) => {
    if(dtp.Tag == "ChangedProgrammatically")
        dtp.Tag = null;
    else {
        dtp.Tag = "ChangedProgrammatically";
        dtp.Value = dtp.Value.AddTicks(_microSecNumericUpDown.Value * 10);
    }
}
```

I think setting the value directly also raised the event, hence the "ChangedProgrammatically" code to debounce it but if it doesn't it can be removed

If you want to also provide the user option to edit the microseconds, add an event to its value changed that takes the current dtp value, strips it to just seconds precision and adds them on:

```
_microsecNud.ValueChanged += (sender,args) => {
  dtp.Tag = "ChangedProgrammatically";
  dtp.Value = dtp.Value.AddTicks(microsecNud.Value - (dtp.Value.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
}
```

If it all works out, perhaps bundle these two controls into a custom user control..

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it can only be done in this way.